How can I read a File chunk by chunk in Typescript (client-side)
I am using a file upload dialog and need to parse that file and send the parsed data to a server part by part.
The file can be really large (100s  MBs) and, as such, reading the file in one go is not desired.
I would like to re-use the same buffer for each subsequent read in order to not have to reallocate and garbage collect the buffer each iteration, especially when the buffer size is small.
In C, such a thing would be relatively easy:
void read_chunks(FILE *file) {
  uint8_t buf[CHUNK_SIZE];
  size_t read_size;

  while (read_size = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file)) > 0) {
    handle_data(buf, read_size)
  }
}

Now, in Typescript, I am trying to do the same, and the only applicable code that I could find was using a ReadableStreamBYOBReader using an ArrayBuffer as backup. But when I try to do this, I get an error:
async readChunks(file: File) {
    let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(CHUNK_SIZE)
    let reader = file.stream().getReader({mode: 'byob'})

    while (true) {
      const {done, value} = await reader.read(new Uint8Array(buffer, 0, buffer.byteLength))
      if (done) break
      if (value) handleData(value)
    }
}

This gives the error:
TypeError: attempting to access detached ArrayBuffer
on the second time I try to call reader.read(). It appears I have to pass a whole new buffer on each invocation, which is very inefficient.
Now, I don't understand what's wrong here since according to the docs: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamBYOBReader/read)

If a chunk of data is supplied, the value property will contain a new view. This will be a view over the same buffer/backing memory (and of the same type) as the original view passed to the read() method, now populated with the new chunk of data. Note that once the promise fulfills, the original view passed to the method will be detached and no longer usable.

Now this would imply to me that the view (the Uint8Array) would be detached (whatever that is supposed to mean) but the buffer would be reusable. But the error seems to imply that the buffer itself is detached.
How can I properly read the file chunk by chunk without having to allocate a new buffer or read the whole file in one go?
Alternative suggestions using third-party libraries instead of the streams API are welcome if this is not easily done using that API as it means I do not have to reinvent the wheel.

I would like to point out that while it doesn't invalidate the question for a file of that size you're better off using FTP or networked drives or some other method of conveyance rather than over HTTP. FWIW.

usually easier to just let the browser post the form.  It'll stream the file.  (I do this: let form = document.getElementById('yourFileUploadFormID')! as HTMLFormElement;
let formData = new FormData(form);
return this.http.post(this.fileUploadURL, formData) { ... }  Since this call could also be made with a simple request consider CSRF implications.  (Implement anti-csrf token if needed)

Also, kind of a follow-on to what browsermator said, have you actually tried just doing a simple form POST? If not you may find that the browser already handles your files just fine without you trying to preempt it. That may also be why you can't find good examples on the net: it might just not be necessary, so nobody's done it.

This question is not about the upload itself, but rather about how to read it in the first place. The data is also needed to be processed by the front end application and after this processing it is sent to the server using gRPC-web. So all your assumptions are incorrect.

I think you'll want something like: reader.read().then(....  it'll fire done when all chunks have been processed.  You need to add to a typed array in there for each chunk?  (never used file reader before)  There's some example code here: https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/streams/simple-random-stream/  Seems to use a set buffer size and that's internal?
